# when i click the button every thing is closed, why it is happening?

Tags: jquery

on my site when i click the hidden costum area button everything is closed.

i dont want to close them when i click this button. but they are closed.

what sould i do for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { background:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted. The point of using Lorem Content is here...

  </p>
  <p>
  <span>Mr [Name], [Surname]</span>
  <a href="http://www.mobilyala.com" />
       <img src="http://www.mobilyala.com/home.png" alt="Home" />
   </a>
   Welcome to our website. You can read all about our services. We are working on dekorasyon

   <button>Hidden Custom Area</button>

</p>
<script>
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("p").empty();
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior - you wrapped all your elements with `<p>` tags, and then you `empty()` their contents.

Answer (score 5):

The code deletes the content of every `<p>` element. What else did you expect?

If you want only the `<p>` containing the button, use thios:

```
$(this).closest('p').empty();
```

Instead of `.empty()` you might also want `.remove()`.